# Tomcat 5: Getting juli exception during tomcat load

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat5.5

While I start tomcat, I am getting the following exception. Could you let me know the reason.
Here is the complete stacktrace.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<init>(JspServlet.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

Thanks
Shafi

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.The tomcat-juli.jar doesn't contain the logging package, so cannot fulfill the search for org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory, which is probably located somewhere else. I'm revisiting a project that hasn't had any work done on it for over a year, and the strange thing is that I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: To address the issue, I had to copy the tomcat-juli.jar from Tomcat6, into my Tomcat 5 installation. This feels wrong on many levels, not least of which is the fact that when my app was originally developed, Tomcat 6 didn't exist - so I can't understand how the app ran before.

Comment: Update: It turned out that there was a copy of catalina.jar in my WEB-INF/Lib directory, and removing it solved the 'juli' issue (and another one too) I have no idea how it got there, so don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

Just perform following steps:

Tomcat's bootstrap.jar used to reference the file bin/tomcat-juli.jar in it's manifest. That is changing since it forced tomcat to use a specific library. Instead, it has to be added to the -classpath line. Open your server configuration, and add tomcat-juli.jar to the classpath, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the JAR `tomcat-juli.jar` is missing or corrupt. Check the Tomcat distribution archive where it should be and install it again.

[EDIT] The stack trace above says `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` wants this class.

Where is `JspServlet` from? Maybe you have deployed `servlet.jar` with your web app?

Did you precompile your JSPs or something? Try to recompile them with the version of Tomcat that you use on the server.

Comment: tomcat-juli.jar is already present under tomcat/bin directory. I tried removing it but it's presence or absence is not making any difference. In both cases, I am getting the same error

Comment: Check the archive. Maybe it was corrupted somehow.

Comment: The tomcat insatllation is from a fresh download, is exactly the same as the installation that's in a backup of the files as they were over a year ago, and neither of the tomcat-juli.jar files contains the logging package. Is this class located in another jar, as is common in the Java world?

Comment: Find out where `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` comes from. I have a feeling that you have deployed servlet.jar or jsp.jar or something with your app.